# Can not resolve svn conflict - two files with same name in repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, conflict

I have a freshly checked-out svn working copy in my eclipse workspace, running on Windows 7. In the repository, both in the same directory, I have the following two files (that only differs by the extension letter case):

```
grey_tube_with_border.PNG
grey_tube_with_border.png
```

Unsurprisingly, Windows isn't happy about it, and cannot hold the two files simultaneously in the working copy. This cause me a lot of troubles (for instance, when I try to merge the WC with a different branch).

On the other hand, I can't find a way to rename / delete one of the files. I tried `commit`, `override and commit` etc. Nothing works.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command-line tools, or the Repository Browser in TortoiseSVN, to do a rename directly on the server without a working copy.

Example:

```
svn move http://example.com/svn/grey_tube_with_border.PNG http://example.com/svn/grey_tube_with_border.2.png
```

Then you should be able to svn update to get any version at or after this rename.

Comment: I was able to rename the file, but now, whatever I do, I have the `grey_tube_with_border.PNG` file marked as missing in my working copy. Of course it's also missing in the repository, so I can't commit the delete, nor update it into my WC. Is there a way to resolve this other then a fresh check-out?

Comment: `svn revert` to get rid of local changes, then svn update doesn't work? If not, then yes I'd try a fresh checkout.